# Read data points from string array

Tags: c#, string, multidimensional-array

I have a text file that contains numbers like this :

```
84 152 100 52 95 186 169 106 37
86 149 101 56 93 181 171 116 37
84 152 100 52 95 186 169 106 37
86 149 101 56 93 181 171 116 37
84 152 100 52 95 186 169 106 37
86 149 101 56 93 181 171 116 37
84 152 100 52 95 186 169 106 37
86 149 101 56 93 181 171 116 37
```

Is there a way to read 2 data points like (84,152) and then (100,52)?

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Farhan Afzal\Downloads\data_1_2.txt");
string[] line = lines.Select(l => String.Join(" ", l.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Assuming that you have a array of Lines and then each lines contains numbers .for loop with step=2 will do

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\items.txt");
var points = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
var items = lines.SelectMany(ln => ln.Split(new[] {' '}).Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)))
                 .ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i+=2)
{    
    int second = (i + 1) < items.Count() ? items[ i + 1] : Int32.MinValue;                
    points.Add(Tuple.Create(items[i], second));
}
```

TODO: error/input format handling

Using [MoreLINQ Batch()](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) this will be just

```
items.Batch(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of side-effect

```
int dummy = 0;
var result = list.GroupBy(x => dummy++%2)
                .Select(g => g.ToArray())
                .ToList();
```

And a long version without side effect

```
var result = list.Select((x,i)=>new {item=x,index=i})
                .GroupBy(x => x.index%2)
                .Select(g => g.Select(x=>x.item).ToArray())
                .ToList();
```